# cannot load Java class uk.co.jaywayco.Parser

Tags: jar, logstash

I am trying to write a custom logstash filter. I have followed the documentation [here](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/extending/example-add-a-new-filter).

My filter (at the minute) looks like:

```
# Call this file 'foo.rb' (in logstash/filters, as above)
require "logstash/filters/base"
require "logstash/namespace"

class LogStash::Filters::NLP < LogStash::Filters::Base

  # Setting the config_name here is required. This is how you
  # configure this filter from your logstash config.
  #
  # filter {
  #   foo { ... }
  # }
  config_name "nlp"

  # New plugins should start life at milestone 1.
  milestone 1

  # Replace the message with this value.
  config :message, :validate => :string

  public
  def register
    # nothing to do
    java_import 'uk.co.jaywayco.Parser'
  end # def register

  public
  def filter(event)
    # return nothing unless there's an actual filter event
    return unless filter?(event)
    if @message
      # Replace the event message with our message as configured in the
      # config file.
      event["message"] = @message
    end
    # filter_matched should go in the last line of our successful code
    filter_matched(event)
  end # def filter
end # class LogStash::Filters::NLP
```

Ive created a very simple logstash config that looks like this:

```
input {
  stdin { type => "nlp" }
}
filter {
  if [type] == "nlp" {
    nlp {
      message => "Hello world! - Youve been NLP'd"
    }
  }
}
output {
  stdout { }
}
```

When i run logstash with the following command:

```
bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/test.conf
```

I get the following error:

```
The error reported is:
    enter code herecannot load Java class uk.co.jaywayco.Parser
```

The java class `uk.co.jaywayco.Parser` is in a jar file located in the `/opt/logstash/lib/logstash/filters` folder. Which is where all the filter scripts reside.

Why wont logstash load my java class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so thanks to the logstash IRC channel

The solution was to add `require 'logstash/filters/myjarfile.jar'` wher the other `require`s are